# Mute / Unmute toggle button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I implemented code to mute background sound on the page with three.js element and it doesn't work, because toggle button is not clickable. Although on page without three.js it works.

Could somebody help me to figure out what might be an issue? Did I place script part in the wrong place?

```html
</div>
<audio id="background_audio" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="sounds/10_EtherealSpace.wav" />
    </audio>
<div>
  <a href="#noscroll" id="mute"><img id="mutebutton" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/189/189653.png"></a>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <script>
    var container, stats;
    var camera, scene, renderer;
    var group;
    var mouseX = 0,
      mouseY = 0;
    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
    init();
    animate();



    function render() {
      camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.05;
      camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * 0.05;
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
      group.rotation.y -= 0.003;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    var audio = document.getElementById('background_audio');

    document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      audio.muted = !audio.muted;
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  </script>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Where ends your `<div id="container">`? Seems like you're missing a `</div>`

Comment: Since your excerpt is missing some essential stuff of three.js which is somehow breaking your code I _guess_ there is some transparent element covering the clickable element. Have you tried right-clicking the button and use "Inspect Element" to see what element is catching clicks in that area?